# DbContext Table mappings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have tried to implement this [scenario](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx). I have created Code First model, then generated database sql from model, and have created manual migrations via [MigSharp](https://github.com/dradovic/MigSharp). After that i have added code to `OnModelCreating` to update mappings.

```
protected  void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("dfg_Product");
  modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("dfg_Customer");
}
```

Problem is that DbContext still trying to get data from default mappings "dbo.Product | dbo.Customer" and I need to change mappings to "dbo.dfg_Product | dbo.dfg_Customer".
I have tried to debug but code in `OnModelCreating` does not invoked.

Please help, what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Added connection string

```
<add name="DataModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/‌​DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Problem was solved by changing connection string to:**

```
<add name="DataModelContainer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code. If OnModelCreating is not getting called at all then it may be that you're not using Code First but instead using an EDMX from your project. What does your connection string look like?

Comment: have added to question. All tables are already created in DB, but with prefix. All i need is to configure EF to add this prefix before table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you executed your application before and your model remains the same, the database is already there and `OnModelCreating()` will not get called.

You can use `Database.SetInitializer()`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Database.SetInitializer(
            new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>());
     //or
     Database.SetInitializer(
            new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContext>());
     //your code
}
```

Also i noticed you're using FluentAPI and i want to point you can also use attributes for mappings:

```
[Table("dfg_Product")]
public class Product
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

You are using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("dfg_Product");
```

and this is why it created dbo.Product. 
Use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().MapSingleType().ToTable("dfg_Product");
```

and please use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways()` so you'll get a new database with correct mappings.

**EDIT 2**

You don't need metadata information in the connection string when developing a Code First application so your connection string should look like this:

```
<add name="DataModelContainer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: tryed to use [Table("dfg_Product")] but it does not help.

Comment: There is no such method like MapSingleType() in EF 4.3. About DropCreateDatabaseAlways. I am using my custom migrations and I want create db by them not by EF. I dont want to use any generation or migration feature of EF. All I need from EF is to get my POCO mapped to tables in DB and provide me access to them.

Comment: Are you defining a connection string somewhere? If so you don't need metadata information in the connection string when developing a Code First application. EDIT: Added connection string to answer.

Comment: plz change "System.Data.EntityClient" to "System.Data.SqlClient" and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Changed it now, my fault for trying to be fast. Glad we worked your problem.